# Allow anonymous access to SSRS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2

How could I allow anonymous access to SSRS so that all user can access the reports without asking for a user name and password?

Comment: are you in an active directory environment?

Comment: Yes im on active directory environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the `Browser` role to the `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users` group to configure the read-only access of the SSRS environment for all the authenticated domain users.

[image]

[Source](http://nikspatel.wordpress.com/2010/05/20/configure-all-domain-users-to-browse-the-ssrs-reports/)

Comment: dude i did this but nothings happen every time preview my reports on client side it always asking for windows authentication

Comment: Are the users in the same AD as the SSRS?

Comment: dude yes they are in the same AD

Comment: Try `everyone` instead then.